# Hardware Failure of Raw_Read_Error_Rate

Tags: external-hard-drive, smart

I have a 1TB WD external hard drive, it is not recognized any more by the PC, but it is visible to the Disk Management (as "Disk 1 unknown, Not initialized, Unallocated"). I used "WD Drive Utilities" program to check what is the problem and the result is "SMART failure" using the "Run Drive Status Check". The other tests did not work.
To find a more specific check results, I used two freewares "HDD Scan" and "DiskCheckup", and both gave me the same results regarding the SMART which is as in the figure below. I want to know what is the exact hardware that is causing this problem. I need just to replace it with a new one to get my data back and then I am not going to use this drive any more.
Note: the Hard drive broke suddenly and I did not drop it or something like that.

I appreciate any help, thank you so much.

[HDDSCcanResults](https://i.stack.imgur.com/arKhs.png)

Answer (score 0):

From what I know, `Read Error Rate` may indicate damaged disk surface or read head damage. I am not really sure about the technicalities of that however, it is something i ignore when checking disks to be honnest. I mainly focus on running self-tests on the drives and then go from there.

As for your data, try using some tool like PartitionGuru which packs a lot of very helpfull utilities, to see if you can save some or all of your data. That would work briliantly if the damage is logical and not physical because if it is physical there is litle you can do.

If you are unable to rescue important data from your drive you may whave to use a data recovery service.